# Getting to the data before your browser :)

Tags: c#

Is it possible to write a program to retrieve data coming in on a socket change it and then send it to the browser and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, it is. By tagging this with C#, do you mean you would like a pointer about how to go about writing a proxy in C#?

Comment: Yes I would like to build some console that can get the data from the port the browsers are using change it and send it on to the browsers.
Would it be better to create a browser Extension insted?

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like is what [fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler2/extensions.asp) does. I don't know if you can get the source code for it, but it might give you a place to start looking as to how it works.

Looks like you can use [Fiddler Core](http://www.fiddlertool.com/Fiddler/Core/) to do what you want. If you want to totally write it from scratch this might give some insight, if not you maybe able to leverage this.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is a [squid proxy.](http://www.squid-cache.org/)
[AdZap](http://librenix.com/?inode=4483) uses squid to do this.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for something they can code themselves in c#